# Can you nest a <paper-icon-button> inside a <gold-phone-input>?

Tags: polymer

There seems to be no issues when nesting a `<paper-icon-button>` inside a `<paper-input>` but when I try to nest a `<paper-icon-button>` inside a `<gold-phone-input>` then it won't show. Is this a bug? I basically want to show a 'X' button that will clear the input when a value is present.  I have a `clearPhoneNumber` function that just checks if the `value > 0` and if it is then it changes the `visibility to "visible";`

```
<gold-phone-input id="phoneNum" country-code="1" label="Phone Number" maxlength="12" value="{{phoneNum}}">
    <paper-icon-button id="btnPhoneNum" suffix on-click="clearPhoneNum" icon="clear" alt="clear" title="clear" style="visibility: hidden;"></paper-icon-button>
</gold-phone-input>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like [`gold-phone-input` accepts a suffix](https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-phone-input/blob/master/gold-phone-input.html#L116) like [`paper-input`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html#L147) does

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought which is what I was afraid of. I was hoping someone on the interwebs knew something I didn't. This should be fixed IMO.

Comment: Feel free to [submit an issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-phone-input/issues) and maybe they'll add it

Comment: It's been submitted. Thanks for the advice